# Regular expressions help

Tags: regular-expression

what the different between these two regex expression ?

AB\{4\} and (AB)\{4\}

for the first expression I  think that it repeat B 4 times, then for second expression it

repeats AB 4 times. When I try to test the second expression using ABABABAB nothing matches.

Comment: What tool are you using as a regex engine?

Comment: I just tested in bash by creating a file and then use grep command

Comment: Try escaping the braces with a backslash

Comment: sorry that was in the original question, I  guess need to put \\ in order to show the backslash on stack exchange

Comment: Write it `(AB){4}` if it's a ERE, `\(AB\)\{4\}` if it's a BRE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

grep by default uses BREs, so you need to escape your parentheses:

```
grep 'AB\{4\}'
grep '\(AB\)\{4\}'
```

You can also use EREs by passing the `-E` option, available on some grep implementations:

```
grep -E 'AB{4}'
grep -E '(AB){4}'
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `-E` is specified by POSIX, and `grep -E` is sometimes available as `egrep` (although this invocation is now deprecated).

Comment: @rahmu POSIX still doesn't cover the entire range of Unices, and `egrep` isn't specified by POSIX.